# about giving same column name in every table of database

Tags: database-design, mysql-5.5, naming-convention

I have a database with 5 tables.
In every table there is a column for checking status.
If i give the name to that column which is same in all the 5 tables; 
What will happen?
Is it correct according to conventions?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip table name prefix in the status column, You can have all the tables with same column name and same datatype, that will make your naming uniform through out the tables in the database

I have seen Database with 2000 of tables, and most of them have column `status` with  same datatype. `TINYINT` in our case.

Let say a query.

```
SELECT T1.columnName...., T2.Column,,...
FROM Table1 T1 
JOIN Table2 T2 ON .....
WHERE T1.Status = 1 and T2.Status =1
```

If the `status` column is only for row data active and inactive, you can choose datatype as `bit` or `TINYINT` incase you are looking to add more option in future

Answer (score 0):

This could become confusing - but it's not difficult to make it work if you really wanted to. Say you had two tables, `TASK` and `PROJECT`. If both tables have fields called `status` and `id`, you can still access them without conflict by referring to them as either `TASK.status` or `PROJECT.status`. E.g:

`SELECT TASK.id, TASK.status, PROJECT.id FROM TASK, PROJECT 
WHERE PROJECT.status != 'COMPLETE'
AND TASK.projectId = PROJECT.id;`

You'll only have a problem if you try to write a query involving both tables and you forget to specify which `status` you want. However, since you have FIVE tables, it's going to be more confusing than in my example with two tables. You might find it easier to implement if you instead gave them each a unique name/prefix, e.g. `prog_status` and `task_status`

Comment: I know it's only an example, but your SQL uses old syntax and is missing a join condition between the tables.

Comment: Whoops, the join is my fault, the other part I'll have to take up with my lecturers...

Comment: You can say with a straight face that typing `task_status` rather than `task.status` makes a real difference other than being slightly slower for an imperfect touch typist to enter?

Comment: I can only speak for myself when I was first learning, but it's just meant to be a conceptual tool. Early on in my learning (SQL and others) it was very important to me that I gave variables/columns unique and descriptive names. When I first faced challenges like the one inspiring this question learning SQL, it really helped me to avoid using the same name to mean different (or equivalent) things on different objects/tables. A lot of early mistakes came down to really boneheaded mistakes like referring to the wrong variable because of confusing or conflicting naming.